# MongoDb change stream isn't restored after collection renaming

Tags: c#, mongodb, changestream

According to [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resumeafter-for-change-streams):

> You cannot use resumeAfter to resume a change stream after an
> invalidate event (for example, a collection drop or rename) closes the
> stream. Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use startAfter to start a new
> change stream after an invalidate event.

I use this code to restore change stream after collection renaming:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("bla");
var student1 = new Student();
var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);

//RESUME TOKEN
BsonDocument resumeToken = null;

var streamListener = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
    var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<Student>>().Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'insert', 'update', 'delete' ] } }");

    using var cursor = collection.Watch(pipeline, options);
    are.Set();
    using var enumerator = cursor.ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    
    //IT'S OK HERE
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    var event1 = enumerator.Current;
    event1.FullDocument.Id.Should().Be(student1.Id);
    event1.OperationType.Should().Be(ChangeStreamOperationType.Insert);
    
    //SAVE RESUME TOKEN
    resumeToken = event1.ResumeToken;
});

are.WaitOne();
await collection.InsertOneAsync(student1);
await streamListener;

//RENAME COLLECTION
await db.RenameCollectionAsync(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName, collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName + "tmp");

collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("bla");
streamListener = Task.Run(() =>
{
    //RESTORE CHANGE STREAM
    var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup, StartAfter = resumeToken };
    var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<Student>>().Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'insert', 'update', 'delete' ] } }");

    using var cursor = collection.Watch(pipeline, options);
    are.Set();
    enumerator.MoveNext();// IT RESTURNS FALSE IMMEDIATELY
});

are.WaitOne();
await collection.InsertOneAsync(student1);
await streamListener;
```

But when I try to restore the change stream (I pass resume token into `StartAfter`) it exits immediately. What's wrong with my code?

- `db.version()` - `4.4.0`
- `MongoDB.Driver` - `2.11.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#startafter-for-change-streams) I found the answer:

> Unlike resumeAfter, startAfter can resume notifications after an
> invalidate event by creating a new change stream.

I added to this list `{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'insert', 'update', 'delete' ] } }` `invalidate` event too and now it's working as expected.